# ArcGIS initial map location jsapi

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-server, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to use a customers ArcGIS system to render a map on a page using the ArcGIS Javascript API.

To define a map in examples it displays:

```
map = new Map("map",{
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [-117.19,34.05], // lon, lat
          zoom: 13
        });
```

however this is showing fixed co-ordinates.

I want to be able to hit the RESTAPI in the customers internal system with a land id and return and plot the co-ordinates.

Currently I am retrieving a Degree Minute Second latitude and longitude from the land but wondering if there is a simpler way then having to get these values as a string, split them into degrees minutes seconds and then making a calculation to get their X,Y values to plot into this function to define a map.

Essentially I am just trying to load a map in a location specified by the land id and then after load map layers on top, all through the the local systems RestAPI and the Javascript API.

Thanks,

Comment: There's nothing overly hard about what you're trying to do - load page (but not map), hit REST API for coordinates, in the callback function initialise the map with the coordinates you get back. It sounds like you're already doing everything you need to do...?

Comment: Which is a long-winded way of saying "...so what's your actual question?" :)

Comment: This is the first time I have dealt with either services as it is just to try and replace old existing .Net2 integration with newer rest and jsapi as I migrate them to my companies product. What I want to do sounds overly difficult for what should be a simple task, e.g needing to convert dms to XYcoords in javascript sounds like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Nevermind. I ended up taking all rings from the land and finding the largest and smallest dimensions and setting the extent to that plus allowing for zoom. This worked.

Comment: I have added an answer below... is it useful to resolve above query?

Answer (score 0):

This is all about spatial reference(i.e 102100, 4326 etc) of the map.
Whatever you will add above snippet code this will add a map with basemap (topology) and center of the map will be co-ordinates which you have provided.

if you want to add a point to map and it has different format of geometry then  you can use project geometry operation to convert.

```
require([
  "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters", ... 
], function(ProjectParameters, ... ) {
  var params = new ProjectParameters();
  params.geometries = [point];
  params.outSR = outSR;
  params.transformation = transformation;
  gsvc.project(params);
  ...
});
```

For Reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#project

**Convert Degree minute second to decimal/Lat long:**

```
function ConvertDegreeAngleToDecimal(degrees, minutes, seconds )
{
    //Decimal degrees = 
    //   whole number of degrees, 
    //   plus minutes divided by 60, 
    //   plus seconds divided by 3600

    return degrees + (minutes/60) + (seconds/3600);
}
```

***Hope this will help you.***

Let me know if you need more clarifications!